# Three Variable Rewrite Rule with city,state, and zip

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm use a rewrite rule and map:

```
mydomain.com/miami-fl-33308/
```

to

```
mydomain.com/city.php?ci=miami&st=fl&zi=33308
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)-(\w+)-(\d+)/? /city.php?ci=$1&st=$2&zi=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Ah Perfect, thank you. I should have have also asked about what I should do if I have a city with a dash in it. Is there a way to handle a dash in the city variable if there is one?                                                                             [code]mydomain.com/saint-petersberg-fl-33308/

to

mydomain.com/city.php?ci=miami&st=fl&zi=33308

Comment: @user2360410 Change `(\w+)-(\d+)` to `([\w-]+)-(\d+)`

Comment: @user2360410 You can select this reply if it helped. The question still appears under unanswered list.